# How do I share a mounted sftp drive?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, samba, sftp, sshfs

My friend has a public server that he's given me read access to with SFTP. I've successully mounted it in Mint 17 with the command

```
sshfs user-name@file-server:/location/I/want /mount/point/I/want -o port=portNumber
```

Now I'd like to share the folder with the people I live with, but I don't want them to set anything up  themselves. Instead, I want them to see a network share that contains the SFTP share.

I've set up a shared folder using Nautilus, and I set my mount point inside of it. It works fine from my local machine and my own user. However, when my friends point their Windows machines at my shared folder it appears empty.

How do I make the mount visible to them?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that "/mount/point/I/want" and all the files and subdirectories have world readable permissions.

Also, if you are not using a user/pass for the Windows machines to authenticate via SMB, then you will need to allow guest access to your share.

Quick and dirty (assuming that you don't have any permissions that must remain as they are under the mount)  This will also change the permissions on the remote (your friend's server):

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /mount/point/I/want
```

Again, if you are not having the Windows machine authenticate with a user/pass that exists on the box running Samba, then you will want to add this to your smb.conf inside your share declaration:

```
guest ok = yes
```

If you still have issues, please post your smb.conf contents.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for getting to me so quickly!
I just ran the chmod command on my mount point and was given access denied. Remember that the share is read only. And even if it wasn't, I wouldn't want to mess up the permissions on my friend's box.